# Linux or Android Driver for KR070PC7S LCD Display

Tags: android, linux, driver, kernel, lcd

I'm trying to build an android linux kernel for an amlogic meson3 processor. Specifically the current running Linux shows the display configuration is

CONFIG_AML_TCON_KR070PC7S

When searching on google, it turns out to be a "60P LCD screen KR070PC7S". However, it seems google does not search the source code repositories around the web to give an answer.

Thus the questions:

1. Where you can find the driver in source code? Or in pre-built obj binary?
2. Where you can find the datasheet of the LCD if the driver is not available?
3. Which other devices (model, brand) use the same display?
4. Is 60P LCD a standard interface? Where is the spec?

Thank you in advance for any answers or hints.

Answer (score 0):

Google does normally index CONFIG_xxx in parts of the Linux mainline kernel OK. I suspect you're running a custom kernel where they haven't merged it back into the mainline and haven't placed the source in a publically indexable area.

There is nothing wrong with the latter under the terms of the GPL as far as I know, but the original hardware vendor should make the modified kernel source available to customers upon request assuming they have based the driver on GPL code. Otherwise they have no obligation to provide datasheets / code etc.

Comment: I believe the source code is somewhere given the popularity of the LCD device since you can easily find it on the net. Thanks for the comment though.